# Graphic fail when rebooting the micro controller and OLED! (NOT when uploading the code??!!)

Tags: uart, arduino-pro-micro

Im using Spark fun´s Pro micro: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/pro-micro--fio-v3-hookup-guide/hardware-overview-pro-micro

And Digole OLED 1.8" hooked up with UART: http://www.digole.com/index.php?productID=859

As the head line reads, got code that work just fine when I upload it to the Pro Micro. But when I restart the pro micro (after successful upload it starts to show these weird characters and tokens. I can still se the "working code" but with a lot of additional crap?!

EDIT: This is installed in a car, and I´ve notice its just screwing around when I turn the car ON.. The cars electric is probably somehow interfering with the data-signal to the oled. Maybe I need a resistor of some kind?

What is this, why is it happening, and what can I do to get rid of the problem?!?

Help´s very appreciated!! Thanks!! /Rasmus

Comment: Try adding a 1000ms delay to the start of your code before you do any serial work.

Comment: @Majenko, ok will try that today! I´ll be back with the result! Thanks!

Comment: Tried with a delay but the problem´s still there.. Thanks anyway for the suggestion @Majenko

Comment: It would have been nice to know the rather important fact you just now mention in your edit... running from a car and it only happens when you start the engine...  Starting the engine is *very* noisy. You need lots of filtering to get rid of the massive spikes, and lots of capacitance to absorb the deep brownouts you get.

Comment: @Majenko, Yeah, and not only during startup, of course also during idle and driving. Do you know what I could use?

Comment: This may help you: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/73921/4245